# Can you explain the background Independence of String Theory?

Tags: string-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Is it possible to prove background independence of string theory? I've seen a few things about it but not really sure how it works. I seems to involve the action:

$$S = \int \sqrt{G}G^{\mu\nu}(X)\eta^{ab}\partial_a X_\mu(\sigma)\partial_b X_\nu(\sigma) d\sigma^2$$

And then expanding out the function $G^{\mu\nu}(X)$ so we get a non-polynomial action in $X^\mu(\sigma)$ to get a theory of string theory on curved space-time. But I can't see how this relates dynamical curved space time to the fields $X^\mu(\sigma)$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking - the standard party line is that string theory formulated like that is *not* manifestly background-independent, so the answer to your question is "you can't". Why do you think you can prove background independence here?

Comment: But is General Relativity  background independent?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342025/50583.

Comment: Perturbative string theory is background-dependent.

Comment: I don't think "is GR background independent?" is a meaningful question, because GR _describes the dynamics of the background_.

Comment: This particular action isn't background independent. However you might want to have a look at AdS-CFT correspondence, where you can precisely formulate questions about background independence in the context of asymptotically AdS spacetimes.